# How to reference a column in another content type?

Tags: content-type, column

In simplified form: I have two content types representing documents and folders. Thus, content type *MyFolder* has parent type *Folder*, content type *MyDocument* has parent type *Document*.

What I want to do now is to have a column *MyColumn* in the *MyDocument* content type that is a reference/link to the column *MyColumn* in *MyFolder*. The desired behaviour is that the value of that column in a *MyDocument* instance is always equal to the value of the same column of the *MyFolder* that contains the *MyDocument*. It should **not** be just a copy of that value, it should be the very same value at all times.

How can I achieve this? Do I need a calculated column for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I assume you are using SharePoint 2010.

If you are willing to use Document Set Feature introduced in SharePoint 2010, they offer Shared Columns, these columns can be updated at document set (it is a content type derived from folder) and automatically synchronized to documents in the document set. Shared columns remain read-only for documents though.

Note that Document Sets themselves are derived from Folder but enhanced with special operations and behaviors. Check more about them:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-configure-a-new-document-set-content-type-HA101782461.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637.aspx

Comment: I am indeed using Sharepoint 2010. I took a look into DocumentSets now, but apparently they cannot be nested which is a must-have requirement.